# Easier way to to my mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a query connected to a database and it works as designed but I feel like I have way more code then needed. Can someone help me out?

Basically I'm trying to get a sum of multiple columns and then assign a variable to the outcome. The variable has to be unique every time so I can echo them out later individually.

Would it be possible to use an array to select a different column and then use that same array to make the variables?

I hope it all makes sense what I'm trying to achieve.

This example is only 3 of the 12 queries I have.

```
$sql = ("SELECT SUM(Case_closed) AS sum_closed FROM production WHERE Datum = '$actual_time' AND jaar = '$year' ");
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql)  ;
            $Case_closed    = $result->fetch_object()->sum_closed;


$sql = ("SELECT SUM(Case_handled) AS sum_handled FROM production WHERE Datum = '$actual_time'  AND jaar = '$year' ");
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql)  ;
        $Case_handled   = $result->fetch_object()->sum_handled;


$sql = ("SELECT SUM(swap) AS sum_swap FROM production WHERE Datum = '$actual_time'  AND jaar = '$year' ");
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql)  ;
        $swap   = $result->fetch_object()->sum_swap;
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: this script if not used for public use so i am not worried about that. thanks for the heads up tho

Comment: I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. Challenge them. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."* or *"Security isn't important now..."*. If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later?

Answer (score 3):

You can use multiple SUM's (example is based on prepared statements):

```
SELECT SUM(`Case_closed`) AS `sum_closed`, SUM(`Case_handled`) AS `sum_handled`, SUM(`swap`) AS `sum_swap` 
FROM `production` 
WHERE `Datum` = ?  
AND `jaar` = ?
```

---

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: I followed @Little Bobby his advice and created a function for the query. Somehow when i use (?) instead of ($type) i do not get results

Comment: The `?`'s are there to illustrate how the query would look when used as a prepared statement. It is just an example as I pointed out in the answer.

Comment: ye i tried to explain in a comment but somehow i could not get the code in correctly so i posted the answer

Comment: You cannot bind column or table names.

Comment: so you would say the way i posted my answer is the correct way?

Comment: It is certainly one way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution by following @little Bobby his advice to make a prepared statement but i failed to to it for the column. Its currently set to `($type)` but i would like to have it `(?)`

```
function resultaten($type){

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
echo mysqli_connect_error();
exit(); 
}   
$query = ("SELECT SUM($type) AS sum_gesloten FROM productie WHERE Datum=? AND jaar=?");

$time = time();
$actual_time = date('d-m-Y', $time);
$year = date("Y");
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection,$query);

if($stmt){
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $actual_time, $year);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $typeresult);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

if(!empty($type)){
    echo "$type $typeresult";       
}else{
    echo "No results!";
}   }else{

echo "Error creating statement object!";
}
}
```

$Case_gesloten = resultaten('Case_gesloten');
echo $Case_gesloten;

Comment: You cannot bind column or table names like `SUM(?)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter